# Include dictionary and context when calling partial in hugo

Tags: hugo

I know you can pass variables into a partial as such:

```
{{ partial "name_of_partial" . }}
```

^^ calls partial and passes current context

```
{{ partial "name_of_partial" (dict "imageUrl" .Params.image "title" .Title "subtitle" .Params.subtitle) }}
```

^^ calls partial and passes "imageURL" as a dictionary with variables.

But what if I wanted to pass the current context and the above dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/accessing-from-partial-that-also-has-a-dict/5162

Summary:

there is currently no way to pass the context i.e. `.` separate to the dictionary. Workaround is to make `.` a variable within the dictionary. e.g.

```
{{ partial "name_of_partial" (dict "imageUrl" .Params.image "title" .Title "subtitle" .Params.subtitle "content" .) }}
```